# Create multiple ROI's using mouse click

Tags: c++, opencv, mouse

My goal is to create a `vector<Rect>`, right now I'm starting with only a single `Rect`, containing any number of ROI's that the user creates within a frame, initially captured from the videocamera. The ROI is created by grabbing points when the mouse is pressed and lifted up.

I know that the code to populate the ROI is working in `onMouse` using commented out `cout`. If I try to print out the ROI in the while loop of the `setup` function it is empty. Did I mess up the pointers or is it something else?

```
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

//Global Variables
Point P1(0,0);
Point P2(0,0);
bool complete = false;

struct MouseParams
{
    Mat img;
    Point pt;
    int lucky;
};


void onMouse ( int event, int x, int y, int d, void *ptr ){
    switch(event){
        //mouse pressed (get coordinate of first point)
        case CV_EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
            cout << "press" << endl;
            P1.x=x;
            P1.y=y;
            break;
        //mouse lifted (get coordinate of final point)
        case CV_EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
            cout << "lift" << endl;
            P2.x=x;
            P2.y=y;
            complete = true;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    //If lifted mosue and have two valid points()
    if(complete && P1 != P2){
        cout << "Building ROI" << endl;
        Rect*ROI = (Rect*)ptr;
        int w,h;
        h= P2.y-P1.y;
        w = P2.x-P1.x;

        ROI->x=x;
        ROI->y=y;
        ROI->width=w;
        ROI->height=h;
        cout << ROI << endl;
        complete = false;
    }
}

Rect setup(Mat frame){
    Rect ROI;
    while(true){
        namedWindow("ROI");
        setMouseCallback("ROI",onMouse, &ROI);
        cout << ROI << endl;
        //draw ROI grabbed in onMouse
        rectangle( frame, ROI, Scalar(0,255,0), 1, 8, 0 );
        imshow("ROI",frame);
        moveWindow("ROI", 0,50);
        waitKey(0);
        return ROI;
    }

}
```

UPDATE: Modify the waitkey() as it was holding up the while loop waiting for an input to move forward. Now code works for retaining the latest ROI (can draw many in setup frame) but need to adapt to retain vector but feel like that is hard to do using pointers.

```
key = (char)waitKey(0);   // explicit cast
        if (key == 27) break;                // break if `esc' key was pressed.
        if (key == ' ') continue;;
    }
    destroyAllWindows();
    return ROI;
```

Comment: Two questions, does `P1 != P2` check for non equality between pointers or non equality between `P1.x` and `P2.x`, et. al. Why check for the truthiness of `complete` if `complete` is always `true` after mouse up? Why not just remove the check for `complete` and extract the if statement to a function, then call said function from mouse up's switch case?

Comment: P1 != P2 is to make sure no accidental double click. The truthiness of complete is rest after the ROI is built to ensure when building another ROI is uses two new points. I also actually got it to work as the issues was with the waitkey(). Now when you click the two points then click the space key it works. However my code currently only retains the latest ROI created. I am now looking to modify to be able to take an vector set of ROI's